# Access SQLite with Jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

I'm experimenting with the jupyterlab ide. I'm working in win7 with git bash. I know its possible to import and interact with csv files (which I can create from my sqllite tables), but is it possible to access a sqllite table directly. (The screenshot shows my sqllite db, in my project root)